# Are there any pro-Israel/anti-Palestinian conspiracy theories?

Tags: israel, 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza, conspiracy-theories

Palestinians and self-proclaimed "Palestinian supporters" routinely engage in conspiracy theories about Israel or downplaying/denying the actions by terrorist groups like Hamas (e.g., the fact that Hamas deliberately killed Israeli civilians or massive sexual violence on October 7):

- [Palestinian Ambassador To Nigeria Abdullah Abu Shawesh On The Eve Of ICJ Hearing: We Have A Feeling That Israel Might Behead And Burn The Corpses Of Palestinian Children It Stole From Gaza To Support Its Lies About October 7](https://www.memri.org/tv/palestinian-ambassador-nigeria-abdullah-abu-shawesh-eve-icj-hearing-israel-behead-burn-corpses-children-gaza-lies-october-seven)
- [Hezbollah's Nasrallah blames IDF for massacre of Israelis](https://www.jpost.com/middle-east/article-771576)
- [Israeli kids killed on October 7 were actors, claims Jeremy Corbyn’s brother](https://www.jpost.com/diaspora/antisemitism/article-771426)
- [Growing Oct. 7 ‘truther’ groups say Hamas massacre was a false flag](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2024/01/21/hamas-attack-october-7-conspiracy-israel/)

Is there similar proliferation of conspiracy theories / denial on the other side? E.g., have any prominent Israeli or pro-Israeli figures claimed that the numbers of Gazans killed are wildly exaggerated, because the only source of the available figures is the Hamas-run [Gaza Health Ministry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaza_Health_Ministry)?

Comment: Your question kind of puts an equal between denial and conspiracy theory, which are not quite the same. You should stick to one or the other.

Comment: That kind of asks how conspiration theories can be distinguished from simple denials? Like is it already a conspiration theory if one says that the numbers being published may be wrong.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution the difference between saying that evidence does not exist, and claiming that the evidence is fabricated

Comment: But what if the evidence is contested? Where does reasonable doubt end and conspiration start? If Hamas says three hundred killed they don't literally mean 299 and one more and give names and photoshoots from multiple angles from everyone and one could say there is maybe only evidence for 30 and the rest is simply extrapolation. There will always be some uncertainty in any of these estimations. The true number could even be higher.

Comment: I have suggested an edit to remove the entire first paragraph which made this a push question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151463/discussion-between-ekadh-singh-reinstate-monica-and-roger-v).

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of pro-Israel "Pallywood" conspiracy
theories. Israel's supporters allege that Palestinains conspire to
produce staged footage of Palestinian suffering to evoke Western
sympathy. One example is the Israeli daily The Jerusalem Post which
claimed that [a Palestinian baby Israel killed was actually a
doll](https://web.archive.org/web/20231201201742/https://www.jpost.com/arab-israeli-conflict/gaza-news/article-776109):

> **Al Jazeera posts blurred doll, claims it to be a dead Palestinian baby**

> Al Jazeera has published on X footage of an emotional man holding a
> ‘baby’ with a blurred face wrapped in white. [...] The footage
> shared on Al Jazeera's X account claimed that the doll was a
> "month-and-a-half-old baby" killed by an Israeli bomb. [...] While
> this footage could not be located on Al Jazeera’s Arabic website,
> other footage was found with adults crying over the death of dolls.

[image]

The Jerusalem Post eventually retracted their story and apologized for
their allegations, but at that point "the doll story" had already
spread far and wide. This example demonstrates one feature of these
conspiracy theories; foreign media is "in on it". Al-Jazeera is
portrayed as a co-conspirator and not just a gullible party.

Another example is [Saleh Al-Jafarawi](https://www.france24.com/en/middle-east/20231121-pallywood-propaganda-pro-israeli-accounts-online-accuse-palestinians-of-staging-their-suffering) who was accused of being a
"crisis actor" working for Hamas. In one story a photo of him was put
next to a photo of a man in a hospital bed, alleging that he was
faking injuries:

[image]

However, the man in the hospital bed is [Mohammed Zendiq](https://observers.france24.com/en/middle-east/20231101-no-this-video-doesn-t-show-someone-pretending-to-be-injured-in-the-war-between-israel-and-hamas) who lost
his leg after Israeli soldiers attacked a refugee camp in July 2023. A
third example the behind-the-scenes footage of a Lebanese film which
showed child actors receiving makeup. The Israeli prime ministers
spokesperson [Ofir Gendelman claimed that it showed Palestinians
preparing to fake injuries](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67760523):

> "See for yourselves how they fake injuries and evacuating 'injured'
> civilians, all in front of the cameras. Pallywood gets busted
> again," Mr Gendelman said in a post that was viewed millions of
> times before being deleted.

Another conspiracy theory accuses the Gazan Health Ministry of
manipulating the death toll to increase sympathy for Gaza. Even the
[White House](https://www.wsj.com/livecoverage/israel-hamas-gaza-war-news/card/white-house-says-hamas-is-exaggerating-death-toll-but-u-n-experts-disagree-xmdvnZkXtu0JXcFnRvrX) alleged that the Ministry exaggerated the death
toll. However, according to both [UN experts](https://www.wsj.com/world/middle-east/palestinian-death-statistics-doubted-by-the-u-s-remain-a-subject-of-controversy-90ead302) and an [article
published in The Lancet](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(23)02713-7/fulltext), the reported death tolls may actually be
underestimates since people could be trapped under rubble.

Comment: The photo of Al-Jafarawi is a legit complaint though.  I think he is a tik-toker or something, not a (confirmed) Hamas hite.  But he did post many different staged-crisis photos of himself, just not as many as are attributed to him.  Referring to Hamas Health ministry is inherently unreliable regardless of what anyone may claim because Hamas is a terrorist organization.  That's not a conspiracy theory.  That's definitional and true of any terrorist organization.

Comment: While I haven't seen any evidence of staged "Pallywood" material from Al-Jafarawi, and I doubt any exists, it is immaterial as a conspiracy theory doesn't have to be false. All that is required is a limited group of people executing a clandestine plot together. Whether statistics from Gaza is reliable is a different question as to whether statistics have been obfuscated. The latter requires a conspiracy, hence the accusation is a conspiracy theory.

Comment: [here's](https://x.com/Shayan86/status/1720306714761711804) one from a BBC fact checker.  He posts 9 images.  He "debunks" the claim that they are all Al-Jafarawi because only 7 of the 9 are.

Comment: It's difficult to tell if the seven other photos are of Al-Jafarawi because they are low-resolution and you get swayed by the claim that they are all of the same person. If they are they indicate that Al-Jafarawi likes to take photos of himself. They do not lend credence to the "Pallywood" theory.

Comment: TBH, "Pallywood" is more like a stereotyping meme than a conspiracy theory. It's just a label that gets attached to various incidents or propaganda.   Official Israeli sources tend not to use the word even when they make [such claims](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56156/did-hamas-release-a-video-of-a-doll-accidentally-masquerading-as-a-dead-child), even giving Hamas the benefit of the doubt as "accidentally" posting such stuff, but their right-wing blogosphere surely uses the "Pallywood" term a fair bit.

Comment: And sometimes even Israeli MSM promotes it as a "fair question" https://www.jpost.com/features/one-on-one-framing-the-debate

Comment: @Fizz "Pallywood" alleges that Palestinians in collaboration with foreign media *conspire* to create false news. It's similar to other conspiracy theories accusing media of misconduct like covering-up of covid-vaccines side effects, helping Joe Biden win the US election, causing climate change hysteria, faking the Sandy Hook massacre, etc. That lots of people (e.g RR here) believe that evidence proves "Pallywood" true doesn't mean it's not a conspiracy theory.

Comment: @StandwithGaza when a BBC fact checker says that 2 of the 9 images are of a different person, it's a reasonable assumption to think that he checked that the other 7 are not.  You may not agree with the label of "Pallywood", but Al-Jafarawi himself describes his videos as performances intended to bring attention to what he sees as a humanitarian crisis in Gaza.  Again, you don't have to agree with the label "Pallywood," but it's incorrect to call it a "conspiracy theory" the suggestion that *many* of these videos are performances rather than news reports.

Comment: It's not clear what your point is. The Pallywood conspiracy theory is about purportedly faked footage of Palestinian deaths or injuries. The seven images the BBC fact checker didn't debunk aren't of Palestinian deaths or injuries. Hence they are not in any way, shape, or form evidence of the truthfulness of the Pallywood conspiracy *whether the photos show Al-Jafarawi or not*.

Answer (score 0):

On October 17th, 2023, there was an [explosion in the parking lot of the al-Ahli Arab Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Ahli_Arab_Hospital_explosion) in Gaza.  News agencies, based on statements from Hamas and the Gaza Health Ministry, initially reported that it was from an Israeli air strike and that there were at least 500 deaths. (Although the 500 number may have come via [misquoting Al Jazeera](https://www.silentlunch.net/p/did-the-entire-media-industry-misquote) which reported *casualties* rather than *deaths*).  The Health Ministry later updated their figures to 342 injured and 471 killed.

The view among Israeli and Western intelligence agencies and many (but not all) analyses by Western newspapers and OSINT groups is that:

1. The explosion was caused by a defective rocket fired by the Palestinian Islamic Jihad.
2. The actual number of deaths was lower (US intelligence estimates are in the 100–300 range and some estimates are closer to 50)

Regardless of what caused the explosion, the death toll has not been independently verified.

Comment: What is anti-Palestinian in this case?

Comment: That would be an example of the Gaza Health Ministry giving inflated numbers, as question mentioned.

Comment: @dEmigOd Claiming that a side in conflict has (inadvetenly or purposedly) bombed their own civilians is a prime example of taking sides, whether supported by the evidence later or not.

Answer (score -1):

I can name one. Just after October 7, some Ukrainian/pro-Ukrainian sources had this conspiracy theory that [Russia was behind Hamas attack](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/11/14/unverified-rumours-of-russia-arming-hamas-persist-as-war-rages-in-gaza).

I believe that would qualify as pro-Israel conspiracy theory as it will partially justify the harsh response in Gaza.

It seems that the topic is largely abandoned by 2024, but this narrative got some amount of push immediately after the October attack.

Comment: I wouldn't classify this as a conspiracy theory. Iran, an ally of Russia, and Russia itself have been supportive of Hamas in various ways.

Comment: When you accuse a country of an indirect terrorist attack but fail to back down up accusation with facts, it is *definitely* a conspiracy theory.

Comment: The reason everyone jumped to that conclusion is that it played very well in Russia's favor (all attention has been diverted from Ukraine, there's now extra pressure on the US to help both Ukraine and Israel and also defend its bases in the middle east), so that theory isn't entirely without facts, although circumstantial. I'd classify this as undetermined until all the secret reports will be declassified.

Comment: There's [also one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXYcRYBqM8o) that Ukraine armed Hamas. Either of these are far fetched as being anti-something-else-than-the-country-accused-of-providing-the-weapons.

Comment: And generally speaking, it's much easier to have almost universal appeal to harsh measures by [comparing or linking Hamas with Isis](https://english.elpais.com/international/2023-11-22/the-weak-points-of-israels-thesis-why-hamas-is-not-the-same-as-isis.html) than by linking them with Russia.

Comment: @Fizz "Ukraine arms Hamas" isn't really pro-Israel since it does not give additional moral ground to Israel.

Comment: Well, I didn't actually say that above. But since you insist on this angle: if anyone but the Kremlin were behind this claim that Ukraine armed Hamas, you could think that the story was meant to reduce the unflinching Russian support for Hamas at the UN, for example. (Ukraine and Russia/Wagner are engaged in a bit of a proxy war in Sudan, for example--Ukraine backs some army forces against the [allegedly Wagner-backed] RSF.)

Comment: re: "When you accuse a country of an indirect terrorist attack but fail to back down up accusation with facts, it is definitely a conspiracy theory."  Wait, are you saying with certainty that it wasn't?  Because strictly speaking if you look at "cui bono," Russia was the main beneficiary.  It didn't help that all the Russian propaganda channels celebrated it.  They were trained with Russian equipment and were coordinating at a level higher than anyone could have trained them to in Gaza.  There was foreign influence.  China is the only other suspect, but China didn't benefit from it.

Comment: In re: "fail to back down up accusation with facts, it is definitely a conspiracy theory". Meh. Russia does that all the time. The "facts" they provide are often circumstantial (cui bono arguments) at best. Yet most (Western) media simply calls those unsupported allegations, or lacking direct evidence, rather than conspiracy theories. The thing is that the latter term has become fairly debased in politics, much like accusations of being a fascist or Nazi, which Russia is often throws around just like that.

Comment: If you read the Wikipedia def (which they cite to a couple of books), it's more than what you assert: "Conspiracy theories are generally designed to resist falsification either by evidence against them or a lack of evidence for them. They are reinforced by circular reasoning: both evidence against the conspiracy and absence of evidence for it are misinterpreted as evidence of its truth." Most things labelled 'conspiracy theory' in politics banter don't quite meet that def. Some of them do, like the seemingly never-ending explanations-upon-explanations of how the US elections were "stolen".

Comment: ... or the 9/11 ones, which RT dutifully backed sometimes (also note their cui bono arguments)  https://www.nature.com/articles/s41562-022-01399-3

Comment: It is true that Hamas situation seems beneficial for Russia, but Russia maintains OK relations with Israel and frankly you do not need malice to get that powder cellar to blow up.

Comment: @alamar ofc, it would be stupid of Russia to admit to helping Hamas. This might push Israel enough to help Ukraine, particularly with the iron dome system. But Russia had been using deception quite often in the past decade in international relations.

Comment: @Ccm: They don't deny supporting them politically, more so than e.g. China. This [includes](https://www.mei.edu/publications/essential-questions-about-russia-hamas-link-evidence-and-its-implications) e.g. inviting to Moscow in March 2023 "senior members of Hamas’ **military leadership**, such as Husam Badran and Saleh al-Arouri." Al-Arouri was recently killed by Israel in Lebanon. It's also true though that Hamas leaders sometimes combine military and political roles. E.g. al-Arouri was apparently deputy chief of Hamas and leader of its armed wing in the West Bank, according wikipedia.

Comment: @Fizz there's a difference between some political level show offs and actually admitting to supplying arms, intelligence and training. Russia long denied they were supplying all those to separatists in eastern Ukraine, so why would they admit to helping Hamas?

Comment: @Ccm: [apparently](https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20230316-hamas-sent-high-level-delegation-to-moscow-at-russias-invitation/), the visits were somewhat controversial within Hamas too. Even they saw rather clearly that they started to get invited to Moscow far more often in the past couple of years. That was al-Arouri 2nd visit to Moscow in like 6 months.

Comment: Additionally, the people in the West who don't care if Palestinians starve are mostly concentrated in the same party as those who don't a give a doodle 'which guy' wins the Russia-Ukraine war; see e.g. https://gaetz.house.gov/media/videos/we-must-not-exploit-war-israel-fund-war-ukraine So this answer is quite tone deaf to Western politics.